# Какие есть способы узнать, из какой функции был вызов, помимо Function.caller?

Tags: javascript

В приведённом ниже коде `machineMonthNumber` - это номер месяца от 0 до 11 (в отличие от `humanMonthNumber` - номер месяца от 1 до 12). Функция `validateMachineMonthNumber(machineMonthNumber)`, как видно из названия, валидирует машинный номер месяца: сначала проверяется тип данных аргумента, потом его целочисленность и наконец, диапазон.

```
function validateMachineMonthNumber(machineMonthNumber){

    if (typeof machineMonthNumber !== 'number') {
        throw new Error('validateMachineMonthNumber() ошибка: тип аргумента должен быть числом'); 
    }

    if (!Number.isInteger(machineMonthNumber)) {
        throw new Error('validateMachineMonthNumber() ошибка: аргумент должен быть целочисленным.'); 
    }

    if (machineMonthNumber < 0 || machineMonthNumber > 11) {
        throw new Error('validateMachineMonthNumber() ошибка: аргумент должен быть целым числом от 0 до 11'); 
    }
}
```

При бросании исключения указано, в какой функции это исключение было брошено. Но функцию `validateMachineMonthNumber()` планируется использовать внутри других функций, а потому сообщение о том, что ошибка исключение произошла именно в `validateMachineMonthNumber()`, хотя и является точным, но не даст информации и том, из какой функции был получен аргумент `machineMonthNumber`. А как это можно узнать?

Метод `Function.caller` имеет статус `depricated`. Какие ещё есть альтернативы?

Comment: Если вы хотите во время РАЗРАБОТКИ узнать, откуда была вызвана функция `validateMachineMonthNumber`, то например, `DevTools` покажет стек вызовов, даже если вызов быд через `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Если же ваи надо логировать эту информацию во время выполнения, то апишите об этом. В общем, проясните ваш вопрос)